# Outlook 2003 stripping out text decoration - HTML Email

Tags: html, email, outlook, outlook-2003, email-client

I having some issues with a client of mine. I've built (not designed) an email template for them to use with Create/Send. I've used the design testing service from Create/Send and all is looking as intended. However, when the client views the email in Outlook 2003 the text formatting is missing (see screen grabs).

There is very little CSS in the head of the document and certainly nothing that should have this affect as much of the styling is done inline.

#### Does anyone have any ideas?

### As intended

[alt text http://citywest.bangtest.co.uk/stackoverflow/okay.png](http://citywest.bangtest.co.uk/stackoverflow/okay.png)

### OutLook 2003

[alt text http://citywest.bangtest.co.uk/stackoverflow/bad.png](http://citywest.bangtest.co.uk/stackoverflow/bad.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

City West e-Bulletin

```
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        * { font-family: Arial, san-serif; }
        a {color:#000000;}
        a img {border:none;}
        h3 a { color: #BD2C16; }
        .topbannercopy a {color:#ffffff;}
        .unsub a {color: #555555; text-decoration:none;}
        .unsub a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
    </style>

</head>

<body style="text-align: left;">

    <table border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="591" align="center" style="font-family: Arial, san-serif;">
        <tr bgcolor="#e95c55">
            <td colspan="4"><img src="img/top-trust.gif" alt="City West Housing Trust. e-Bulletin for Staff" width="591" height="195"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#e95c55">
            <td style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 11px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;" colspan="4"><$description default=''$></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#e95c55" colspan="4">
                <img src="<$imagesrc link='true'$>" alt="read more" width="591">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#e95c55" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">
            <td colspan="1" style="color: #BD2C16; padding-left: 10px;">
                <h3 style="font-size: 15px;"><$title link='true'$></h3>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 20px;"><span class="topbannercopy"><$description default=''$></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" style="font-size: 10px;">
            <td width="133" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <img src="<$imagesrc link='true'$>" alt="read more" width="133" height="118">
                <h3 style="color: #BD2C16; margin-bottom: 5px;"><$title link='true'$></h3>
            </td>
            <td width="133" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 9px;">
                <img src="<$imagesrc link='true'$>" alt="read more" width="133" height="118">
                <h3 style="color: #BD2C16; margin-bottom: 5px;"><$title link='true'$></h3>
            </td>
            <td width="133" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 9px; padding-right: 20px;">
                <img src="<$imagesrc link='true'$>" alt="read more" width="133" height="118">
                <h3 style="color: #BD2C16; margin-bottom: 5px;"><$title link='true'$></h3>
            </td>
            <td width="133" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <img src="<$imagesrc link='true'$>" alt="read more" width="133" height="118">
                <h3 style="color: #BD2C16; margin-bottom: 5px;"><$title link='true'$></h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" style="font-wieght: bold; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 12px;">
            <td width="133">
                <p><$description default=''$></p>
            </td>
            <td width="133" style="font-wieght: bold; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 9px;">
                <p><$description default=''$></p>
            </td>
            <td width="133" style="font-wieght: bold; padding-left: 9px; padding-right: 20px;">
                <p><$description default=''$></p>
            </td>
            <td width="133">
                <p><$description default=''$></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" valign="top"><img src="img/slash-left.gif" width="133" height="50" alt=""></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="3" valign="top"><img src="img/slash-right.gif" width="458" height="42" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="right">
            <td colspan="3" style="font-size: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="right">
            <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 10px;">City West, the City West Logo and all other City West product or service names are<br>trade marks of City West. All Rights Reserved. <unsubscribe>Unsubscribe</unsubscribe>.</td>              
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: +1 for screenshots, but please also show some HTML code.

Comment: You're using inline styles, which is recommended. I'm curious why you're using a stylesheet at all, since support for Outlook is spotty. Are the styles that are being violated inline or by selector in a global stylesheet? Code would help a LOT!

Comment: @Unicron - I've added the code for the entire email as requested (although the top bit looks to be displaying a little incorrectly). Thanks for the Vote up.
@Steven Xu - Because I'm using Create/Send I can't apply inline style to paragraphs and links, etc. as they don't exist at the point of building the template.

Comment: You clearly already have inline styles (notice all the `style` tags). I infer that you mean that Create/Send doesn't allow you to force inline styles. In this case, you should probably take it up with their support agents. If you're using third party software for this, you're going to have to play within their rules. SO can't really help you since we're dealing with a generator rather than your own source code.

Comment: No problems Steve Xu, thanks for your advise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502111/outlook-2010-not-respecting-css-even-font-tags-for-every-text/20461888#20461888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found out that the version of Outlook that the client has uses the rendering engine from whatever version of IE is installed. In this instance it's IE6! I've since tested and made amends to the template and all is now good.

Thank you everyone for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Your stylesheet is being ignored (which is the expected behaviour in Outlook). Convert those to inline styles and you're done! Last time I checked, Gmail also ignores stylesheets, so you're better off just not using them.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, it's also ignoring the inline styles. I've ran a 'design test' using Create/Send but that shows that it's displaying as intended.

Comment: You are correct. I apologize for not looking with more discretion. Looking back on my past email newsletters, it seems as though I avoiding all CSS. Between `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` and `<font>` tags, I remember I had quite a bit of success (despite ugly markup). Your target design seems much simpler than stuff I've done in the past and well within the reach of old school HTML. Best of luck!

Comment: The design was intentionally kept simple to increase the speed of building. As I've said to Jonny (see below) I can't replicate the issue! The client is a large public sector housing association and have some very strange firewall/server setup over there!

Comment: @Shaun is it 1000% sure they are using Outlook 2003? Maybe they have style support turned off completely? In which case you'll have no alternative but to ignore them, or to resort to images. (Yuck!)

Comment: @Unicorn - it's certainly Outlook 2003 SP3. I've got their IT guys on the case but getting anything done over there can prove difficult. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Shaun Yeah, that sort of request will unfortunately go straight to the bottom of the IT pile. I think the best solution for you would be not to worry about the enterprise and just work around their restrictions (in this case no CSS), which at the end of the day isn't prohibitively difficult.

Comment: @Steven Xu It isn't the CSS that the email client is knocking out as the elements affected are controlled by inline styling!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the styles for the fonts and use the `<font>` tag. E.g.

```
<td style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 11px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;" colspan="4"><$description default=''$></td>
```

Turn into:

```
<td style="padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;" colspan="4"><font color="#ffffff" size="11px"><$description default=''$></font></td>
```

Comment: Even adding the `<font>` tag inside the `<a>`? And removing the styles from the head?

Comment: I didn't remove the styling from the top but it wasn't relied upon. I'm finding it really hard to replicate the issue to be honest!