# Outlook 2010 not respecting CSS, even <font> tags for every text

Tags: css, fonts, outlook

We need our emails to look good on machines that have Helvetic Neue. So our font stack is:

```
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',HelveticaNeue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

We have the style declarations in each TD, each DIV, each TABLE, even BODy and everything. Still, Outlook breaks and defaults to an ugly Times New Roman when it doesn't find the first font in that listing -- isn't it supposed to go through the fonts and show the ones that do exist (Arial on Windows)?

Frustrated, we even put these style declarations in ugly and laborious `<font>` tags all around the text. Any and all text has these declarations, with the styling done all over again inside the font tag's `<style>`.

Litmus shows Outlook 2003, 2007 and 2010 showing these properly in Arial on Windows.

Yet, at our office, all the folks are receiving these emails in Times New Roman. What am I missing? Any directions or pointers about why Outlook 2010 (the version we use) forces everything to Times New Roman?

Other questions, such as this one -- [Outlook 2010 overriding font-family from Arial to Times New Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457006/outlook-2010-overriding-font-family-from-arial-to-times-new-roman) -- do NOT answer the question.

Thanks! Below is an example of code:

`

```
<table align="center" width="95%" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,'Arial Unicode MS',Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;color: #999999;border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr>
      <td height="18" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,'Arial Unicode MS',Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;color: #999999;border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border-collapse: collapse;">
         <span class="hide-on-small" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,'Arial Unicode MS',Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #999999;  ">Rummy & Bingo Monthly<img src="http://d3cbux4et72c14.cloudfront.net/wtd2/sep.jpg" alt=" - " width="55" height="10" style="border: 0;">  </span>Issue <span style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,'Arial Unicode MS',Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #999999;  ">05</span> <img src="http://d3cbux4et72c14.cloudfront.net/wtd2/sep.jpg" alt=" - " width="55" height="10" style="border: 0;"> <span style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,'Arial Unicode MS',Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #999999; ">Aug 2013</span>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

`

Comment: Can you share a little bit more of the code? I would like to see everything before font-family.

Comment: Yes; are other styles used correctly?

Comment: Yes, the `style` tag code seems valid. I've edited the original post with some code sample (can't add enough code in comments), which shows in the proper font EVERYWHERE, except Outlook:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style>.outlook { font-family: arial, sans-serif; }</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <table align="center" width="95%" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
        <tr>
            <td class="hide-on-small" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #999999;">
                <span class="outlook">Rummy & Bingo Monthly</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

- I removed the unnecessary reiterations of your font-style declaration.  There's no need to declare it anywhere other than the TD.
- I moved your font-style declaration from the span to the TD along with your CSS class assignment of "hide-on-small".

The font-style was separated from the  specifically to fix your Outlook problem.
 - In the head, below any other CSS you may have declared, I added a conditional comment which will only be read by Outlook.  Within this comment is a CSS class which will tell outlook that the font is Arial.  Therefore Outlook will completely ignore the fact that your using a font that isn't available, thus negating any reason for it to find its own substitution.

Also, pulled out your inline CSS border-collapse declaration because you can just declare that in the head and in the body, give all your tables an attribute of border="0".  Instead of writing style="border-collapse:none;" a dozen or more times.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works. :)

Comment: Your welcome.  Happy I could help.  I've been doing a lot of narly stuff with emails lately.  If you run into any more problems with email stuff, hit me up.